# curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL. What does this mean?

Tags: curl, roboflow

I got this command from an online tool and it is supposed to be

```
base64 test.jpg | curl -d @- \ "https://detect.roboflow.com/sidepanel-new/1?api_key=[MYAPIKEY]"
```

I am not sure why it isn't working

Comment: try removing the `\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the backslash in that command was meant to escape a newline. But since this was put all in one line it's not necessary.

If that's not the issue, please post the error message your received.